# How to remove item in JTable also remove from Database?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, database-connection

I am pretty basic to link from Java to Database.
I link item from Database (I use MS.Access) to Java table (JTable)
but when I delete in JTable using this code

```
int numRows = tblweng.getSelectedRows().length;
for(int i=0; i<numRows ; i++ ) 

((DefaultTableModel)tblweng.getModel()).removeRow(tblweng.getSelectedRow());
```

it deletes only in Table but not in Database. So how I can remove both of them at the same time I click "Remove Button".
Please guide me but don't go too deep I am just a basic here. Thank in advance.

Comment: Wrap the management functionality up in the table...

Comment: um...how?can you tell?

Comment: Override the `removeRow(...)` method of your TableModel. First you would remove the row from the Database. If that is successful, then you would invoke super.removeRow(...) to remove the row from the JTable.

Comment: remove the row from Database?

Comment: @KashamaShinn What you want to remove db or jtable?

Comment: I want to remove in Jtable by click Remove button..so it also delete in db....

Comment: the thing is after click it did remove but still appear in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. click Jtable // row selected
2. get data form dep_Table like 
 int a = dep_Table.getSelectedRow();
 String b = String.valueOf(dep_Table.getValueAt(a, 1)); 
3. What data you want in you get and store in String
4. Connect Database
5. use Delete Query and Delete Data From Database 
6. Reload Table Again
```

These Few basic Step is Enough for You.. I Think..

Comment: kinda not understand...
but what you told me can remove one data at a time right?

Comment: @KashamaShinn remove data from database and reload table

Comment: @KashamaShinn You Said " Please guide me but don't go too deep I am just a basic here"

Comment: @KashamaShinn Show me your delete Query

Comment: DELETE FROM User Where SupplierID="+???+"

??? dont know what to put in there....
[I am basic leaner so dont blame me]

Comment: @KashamaShinn I'm not blame you.. which column you have put supplier id in jtable i mean sno,supplierid,status so here 2nd column you have supplier id. which column you have supplier id in jtable?

Comment: `String value0=tfSupID1.getText();
       int id= Integer.parseInt(value0);
           String sql = "DELETE FROM User Where SupplierID="+id+"";`