# How to update specificed data from JTextField into Database?

Tags: java, swing, database-connection

I have Jtable and when I click (select) it goes to textfield. 
What I want is when I edit in the textfield it also change in database. However everything work only that my edition data have changed every other data. pls look at the picture.
After edit I click OK then click refresh all data become like that...[image: attachment]

here is my OK button code:

```
 private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:mydata";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
    String value1=tfSupName1.getText();
    String value2=tfType1.getText();
    String value3=tfStock1.getText();

    String sql="UPDATE User set SupplierName='"+value1+"' ,MarbleType='"+value2+"' ,InStock='"+value3+"'";

    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   pst.execute();
    }catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}
}
```

Comment: In your update Query doesn't have where condition. Get Supplier Id also..  String sql="UPDATE User set SupplierName='"+value1+"' ,MarbleType='"+value2+"' ,InStock='"+value3+"'" where supplier id=1; like that

Comment: I add one more textfield ID with new sql statement:

    String sql="UPDATE User set SupplierName='"+value1+"' ,MarbleType='"+value2+"' ,InStock='"+value3+"' WHERE ID='"+value0+"'";

but get this error![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UhZT4.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think In your Database table have Supplier_id column as Integer...

Add Supplier id in Your form...

When click on jtable supplier Id also displayed in textfield..

[image]
like this..

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:mydata";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
        String value1=tfSupName1.getText();
        String value2=tfType1.getText();
        String value3=tfStock1.getText();
        String sql="UPDATE User set SupplierName='"+value1+"' ,MarbleType='"+value2+"' ,InStock='"+value3+"' Where Supplier_id=1";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.execute();
    }
    catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}

    }
```

Comment: I did that and get error i.stack.imgur.com/UhZT4.png

Comment: i think maybe because I am not yet convert string to int
this is my code
`String value0=tfSupID.getText();
        String value1=tfSupName1.getText();
        String value2=tfType1.getText();
        String value3=tfStock1.getText();
        
        String sql="UPDATE User set SupplierName='"+value1+"' ,MarbleType='"+value2+"' ,InStock='"+value3+"' WHERE ID='"+value0+"'";`

Comment: I did like you said but it only change when I go to edit code "where id=1"

without go to code...how to do it?
using all method I get error too few parameter.

Comment: @KashamaShinn if int data type in database use where id= " +value0+ "; if String in db means where id=' "+value0+" ';

Comment: can please provide me a bit help?
I am realyl dont know what to do now.

whatever i put is error "too few parameter" but input int 1 or 2 or 3 work but only change that ID not other @sathya

Comment: ***String value0=tfSupID.getText(); String value1=tfSupName1.getText(); String value2=tfType1.getText(); String value3=tfStock1.getText(); String sql="UPDATE User set SupplierName='"+value1+"' ,MarbleType='"+value2+"' ,InStock='"+value3+"' WHERE ID="+value0+"";*** Try this

Comment: I get it...thank so much @sathya you are the best.

`String value0=tfSupID1.getText();
       int id= Integer.parseInt(value0);
Where SupplierID="+id+"`

Comment: You use simply where SupplierID="+value0+";

Comment: one more thing..pls provide answer about my question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23099923/how-to-remove-item-in-jtable-also-remove-from-database?noredirect=1#comment35309895_23099923